# Can't change the bootstrap-toggle state with jquery

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, angular-bootstrap-toggle

I encountered an issue trying to check some bootstrap (4) toggles;

I've a table with 6 columns and about 40 lines.

I would like, when a button is pressed, to toggle "on" all the line associated.

For instance, a line looks like:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" id="t7_1">
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" id="t7_2">
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" id="t7_3">
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" id="t7_4">
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" id="t7_5">
<input type="checkbox" data-toggle="toggle" id="t7_6">
```

the button calls a jquery function this way:

```
selectLine(7, 6);
```

Where the 6 is the number of checkboxes in a line (I hope I'm clear enough...)

The function body is:

```
function selectLine(line, terrains) {
      var i;
      for(i = 1; i <= terrains; i++){
        $('#t' + line + '_' + i).bootstrapToggle('on');
      }    
}
```

But it doens't work... I'm sure my mistake is pretty obvious but I can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

For me its work's correctly,where and when you call your function
selectLine()? If you want you can load the function right after the page load, like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  selectLine(7,6);
});
```

Comment: I've a button like this:                                                                                             
`<button class="btn btn-secondary btn-sm" onclick="selectLine({{ $i }}, {{ $nbre_terrains }});"><i class="far fa-check-square"></i></button>`